# Twill/Mechanize access to html content

Tags: python, twill, mechanize-python

Couple of questions regarding [Twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) and [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

1. Is Twill still relevant as a web-automation tool?  If yes, then why is not currently maintained?  If no, has Mechanize matured further to support Twill-style simple scripting? Or is there another package that has stepped up to fill the gap?
2. I was able to very quickly setup a couple of test suites in python using Twill, but I'm a little confused on how to access the information that Twill spits out in my python program.  That is, I can do showforms() and see the form values neatly listed and I can use fv to update the form values and submit.  But how do I access one of those form values as a python var?  How can I say something like: `someField1Value = fv("1","someField1")`

Answer (score 1):

Twill is a [thin shell around the mechanize package](http://twill.idyll.org/python-api.html). You are right it does not appear to be actively maintained so I would stick with Mechanize.

However Mechanize does not support the simple interface you are after. For that I would recommend [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but ranking high on google.

As of 2014 oficial twill seems quite dead, also the mailing list.

There are forks on github:

https://github.com/zenoss/twill

https://github.com/ctb/twill